# WL.Client.Logout() when app is shutdown

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having a problem with `wl.client.connect()` and `wl.client.logout()`.

If a user logs in successfully, a token and roles are remembered among other things. We save these vars while in our challenge handler functions of the `wl.client.connect()` auth.

But if they login, then shut down the app, opening the app again and trying to log in, I get a `wl.client.connect()` onSuccess, but since it has not gone through the challenge handlers, I don't get any tokens and roles that I need to save.

Do I need to, or is it possible, to run `wl.client.logout()` when they kill the app?

Comment: The problem description is not clear, but anyway, you cannot detect the quit event of the app and run logic before that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you Quit your application manually  then you can fire this API

```
WL.Client.logout("AuthRealm",{
         onSuccess: function(){ 
            WL.Client.reloadApp();
            },
         onFailure: function()
         { WL.Logger.debug("Error on logout");
         }
     });
```

on the other hand , you cannot detect the quit event of the app. it is really impossible

Comment: Thats what i thought, thanks, i used a workaround if it doesnt use the challangeHandler then i make an adapter call

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Cordova documentation for event listeners. The closest that I found would be "pause", which is triggered when you move the app to the background.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.pause.html

You could listen for a pause and do a `WL.Client.logout("<realm-name>")`.